# Bash || within if []; block

Tags: bash, file

I have code matching:

```
if [ $LAST_MODIFIED -lt 3600 || ! -f "$i" ]; then
    wget $WGET_OPTS $BASE$i
    LAST_MODIFIED=`echo "\`date +%s\` - \`stat -c %Y $i\`" | bc`
    if [ $LAST_MODIFIED -lt 500 ]; then
        $FILES_MODIFIED++
    fi
fi
```

`$i` is defined via

```
for i in `/bin/grep ".gz" index.html | awk -F\" '{print $2}'`
```

however, bash tells me

```
[: missing `]'
```

and

`-f: command not found`

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be

```
if [ $LAST_MODIFIED -lt 3600 ] || ! [ -f "$i" ]; then
```

`[` (and `!`) are shell built-ins.  They are not part of the syntax for `if`.

Comment: If your interested, [ is generally a symbolic link to the 'test' command.  So you can do a man on test.

Answer (score 9):

You should either use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` or use `-o` instead of `||`.

```
if [[ $LAST_MODIFIED -lt 3600 || ! -f "$i" ]]; then
```

or:

```
if [ $LAST_MODIFIED -lt 3600 -o ! -f "$i" ]; then
```

See here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite your if as

```
if [ cond a ] || [ cond b ]; then
...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`[` is an actual builtin command, that requires `]` as it's last argument.

However your syntax makes the last argument to `[` "`3600`", and then starts a new command..

Try making the command between the `[` and `]` a single command.

Comment: really all the other answers are great, so I'll just remove the bad example.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the bash `[` built-in command must honor the syntax requirements of the external `/bin/[` command (usually a link to `/bin/test`) in order to maintain backward compatibility with the archaic versions of sh in which `test` (`[`) was NOT internal to the shell.

In order to honor that level of compatibility the parser must treat || as a separator to a new command, thus terminating the `[` command.  When `/bin/test` is called as `[` (it checks its on argv[0]) then it requires the closing "]" as a parameter.

Use -o (or) in your test (`[`) commands.

(Personally I think it's a bad idea do use the `[` form of `test` for exactly this reason.  Novices will think of it as a syntactic feature ... a sort of conditional expression construct to the `if` statement, expecting semantics which are not consistent with its implementation as command.  So I teach it as `test` even though I use it (sometimes) as `[` because the practice is so widespread.